# Capture and handle multiple errors in sequence

Tags: r, error-handling

I have an expression that spits out multiple errors:

```
stop("first")
stop("second")
stop("third")
print("success")
```

Is there a way to make this expression run all the way to the end (and, if possible, store all of the errors)?

The problem with `tryCatch` is that it stops execution on the first handled condition (so this will print "There was an error" exactly once).

```
tryCatch({
  stop("first")
  stop("second")
  stop("third")
  print("success")
}, error = function(e) print("There was an error"))
```

I read that `withCallingHandlers` will capture conditions and continue execution, so I tried something like this...

```
withCallingHandlers(
  {...},
  error = function(e) print("There was an error")
)
```

...but, although this does print the message, it also fails after the first error, which, as far as I can tell, is because the default restart just runs the current line again.

I think what I need to do is write a custom restart that simply skips the current expression and jumps to the next one, but I'm at a bit of a loss about how to go about that.

(Background: Basically, I'm trying to replicate what happens inside `testthat::test_that`, which is that even though each failing expectation throws an error, all expectations are run before quitting).

Comment: You would need to wrap the individual errors in `tryCatch`.  So each call to `stop` (or more likely I'm guessing this is a fabricated example and there are functions that are called that *could* produce errors) needs to be wrapped in its own call to `tryCatch` within the `myf` function.

Comment: I know that would work, but there must be an alternative way to do it, based on how `testthat::test_that` works.

Comment: Everything in testthat gets wrapped in its own function.  It does a lot of wrapping so that things get passed up the calling chain properly to keep track of what produced an error.  But you don't just put random code in - you use the functions provided and they take care of making sure things work the way they should for a testing environment.  If you're interested in how that happens I'd suggest looking at the source for testthat.